# ReactJs Functional Component - How to call function from outside?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

How to call a function from outside of the functional component.

I have a functional component like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
 
const Hello = () => {
  // call updateField() here
};
 
const Headline = () => {
  const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState(
    'Hello Function Component!'
  );
// Function inside Headline, I want to call this function in Hello()
const updateField = () => {
}
 
  return <h1>{greeting}</h1>;
};
 
export default Headline;
```

I want to call updateField() in Hello() outside of Headline(). Please suggest.

Comment: You don't. You *can't*, that function is only accessible inside the scope of the component function.

Comment: Assuming `updateField` changes some state, you should move that state up to `Hello` and have it pass the data which `Headline` needs via props

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do this,

Method 1: Move the common state to a parent component

```
const ParentComponentWithHelloAndHeadline = () => {
   const [field, setField] = useState()
   const updateField = () => { ... }
   
   return (
     <>
       <Headline field={field} updateField={updateField} />
       <Hello updateField={updateField} />
     </>
   )
}
```

Method 2: Use [React.Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) (avoids prop-drilling, incase that is a concern using method 1)

```
const CommonContext = React.createContext({
  field: 'commonField', 
  updateField: () => { ... }
})

const Hello = () => {
  const { field, updateField } = useContext(CommonContext)

  // call updateField() here
};
 
const Headline = () => {
  const { field, updateField } = useContext(CommonContext)
  
  const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState(
    'Hello Function Component!'
  );
 
  return <h1>{greeting}</h1>;
};
 
export default Headline;

function RootApp() {
  return (
    <CommonContext.Provider>
      <Headline />
      ...
      ... 
      <Hello />
    </CommonContext.Provider>
  );
}
```